# Exporting panda data frame as excel file on FTP

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, ftp

I am exporting a panda data frame as an excel file on FTP and using the below code. The code is creating a file on FTP. The issue here is that if I am make any change in the code and expecting a different output file it is creating the same output file as before. However if I change the file name in: `myFTP.storbinary('STOR %s.xlsx' %filename,bio)`..It works fine. Moreover, if I made the output on my local keeping the same name it also works fine. I dont want to change the file name every time I make some change in my code.**"It is not creating a different file with the same name"** Below is the code:

```
myFTP = ftplib.FTP("ftp address","username","password)
myFTP.cwd("change directory/")
buffer=io.BytesIO()
df.to_excel(buffer,index=False)
text = buffer.getvalue()
bio = io.BytesIO(text)

file name = 'FileName_{0}{1}'.format(current_year,current_month)  
myFTP.storbinary('STOR %s.xlsx'%file_name,bio)

myFTP.close()
```

**Name of the output file must be: FileName_currentyearcurrentmonth**

Answer (score 0):

```
file name = 'FileName_{0}{1}'.format(current_year,current_month)
```

If this line of code is as it is in your code, well. It seens you have a syntax error. Also in cases like this contextual manager are actually pretty usefull. Why dont you try doing like this. So if you get an error well you dont keep your file open

```
with ftplib.FTP("ftp address","username","password) as myFTP:
    myFTP.cwd("change directory/")
    buffer=io.BytesIO()
    df.to_excel(buffer,index=False)
    text = buffer.getvalue()
    bio = io.BytesIO(text)

    file name = 'FileName_{0}{1}'.format(current_year,current_month)  
    myFTP.storbinary('STOR %s.xlsx'%file_name,bio)
```

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually I used format only in the code and there is no syntax or any other kind of error. I am getting the excel file as an output on FTP..The only issue is that the file is carrying the old data and not new if I dont change the file name. Also while running the code,I am keeping all the file closed.